When I Install SQLite it's get removed auto
I was trying start an empty ASP.NET project and I needed to install SQLite 3. I used PowerShell to install it and it just stays there for a second - then disappears. I don't know why...
I tried to reinstall package, change version but it didn't work.
Program.cs:
using StoreApp.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Uygulamaya diyor ki : bir servis desteği ekle, servis = .... örneğin api ile çalışsaydık add controller diyebilirdim mesela 
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// ConnectionString'imi ayarladım
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlconnection"));
});

// Bu service kaydı yapılınca middleware ile kullanılabiliyor
// Hem controller hem de view eklemek istediğim için böyle yaptım
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Errors

Error CS1061
'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlite' and no accessible extension method 'UseSqlite' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
StoreApp  C:\Users\Can\Desktop\Ders\Asp Dersleri\Ders3-Veri Odaklı Geliştirme\StoreApp\StoreApp\Program.cs    13  Active`
Error CS0234
The type or namespace name 'Sqlite' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
StoreApp  C:\Users\Can\Desktop\Ders\Asp Dersleri\Ders3-Veri Odaklı Geliştirme\StoreApp\StoreApp\Program.cs    2   Active

The command I used to install the package is:
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -Version 6.0.16


SQLite 3? The command says 6.What if you don't specify a version?

yeah you're right, i got that. thanks
